# Creation of objects by using a primitive operation

Tags: ada

My question contains a longer piece of Ada code. Basically I tried to model a message with a title in a object oriented way. The two primitive operations `Create_Message` and `Create_Message_Access` can be used to create concrete message objects. I'm not really sure if the primitive operation should return the type `Message_Type` or `Message_Type_Access`. Which type is recommended (efficiency?) or are both solutions are not optimal?

I think in the first way the object is created on the stack and then copied after the `return` statement is executed because the variable `Object` goes out of scope. Right or wrong?

```ada
function Create_Message (Title : String) return Message_Type is
   Object : Message_Type;
begin
   Object.Title := To_Unbounded_String (Title);

   return Object;
end Create_Message;
```

I think in the second way the object is created on the heap and then the **pointer** is copied after the `return` statement is executed because the variable `Object` goes out of scope. Right or wrong?

```ada
function Create_Message_Access (Title : String) return Message_Type_Access is
   Object : Message_Type_Access := new Message_Type;
begin
   Object.Title := To_Unbounded_String (Title);

   return Object;
end Create_Message_Access;
```

Later I created an example object with a title, used the primitive operation `Updated_Title` to change the title and change it back at the end.

```ada
First_Message := Message.Create_Message ("First");

Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (First_Message.Get_Title);

First_Message.Update_Title ("First changed");

Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (First_Message.Get_Title);

First_Message.Update_Title ("First");

Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (First_Message.Get_Title);
```

The output is (as expected):

```
First
First changed
First
```

Then I saved the message in a vector container and tried to change the title while iterating over the elements stored in the vector. I found out that the title keeps the old value so I assume calling the operation `Message_Vector.Element (Message_Cursor)` returns only a copy of the message stored in the vector. Right or wrong?

```ada
Messages.Append (First_Message);

Message_Cursor := Message_Vector.First (Messages);

while Message_Vector.Has_Element (Message_Cursor) loop
   declare
      Temporary_Message : Message.Message_Type;
   begin
      Temporary_Message := Message_Vector.Element (Message_Cursor);
      Temporary_Message.Update_Title ("First changed");
   end;

   Message_Vector.Next (Message_Cursor);
end loop;

Message_Cursor := Message_Vector.First (Messages);

while Message_Vector.Has_Element (Message_Cursor) loop
   --
   -- Prints "First" and not "First changed"
   --
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Message_Vector.Element (Message_Cursor).Get_Title);

   Message_Vector.Next (Message_Cursor);
end loop;
```

Last question: What is the difference between `Second_Message.all.Get_Title` and `Second_Message.Get_Title`?

```ada
Second_Message := Message.Create_Message_Access ("Second");

Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Second_Message.all.Get_Title);
Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Second_Message.Get_Title);
```

Full source code:

```ada
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is

   package Message is

      type Message_Type is tagged private;

      type Message_Type_Access is access Message_Type;

      function Create_Message (Title : String) return Message_Type;

      function Create_Message_Access (Title : String) return Message_Type_Access;

      function Get_Title (Self : Message_Type) return String;

      procedure Update_Title (Self : in out Message_Type; Title : String);

      function "=" (Left, Right : Message_Type) return Boolean;

   private

      type Message_Type is tagged record
         Title : Unbounded_String;
      end record;

   end Message;

   package body Message is

      function Create_Message (Title : String) return Message_Type is
         Object : Message_Type;
      begin
         Object.Title := To_Unbounded_String (Title);

         return Object;
      end Create_Message;

      function Create_Message_Access (Title : String) return Message_Type_Access is
         Object : Message_Type_Access := new Message_Type;
      begin
         Object.Title := To_Unbounded_String (Title);

         return Object;
      end Create_Message_Access;

      function Get_Title (Self : Message_Type) return String is
      begin
         return To_String (Self.Title);
      end Get_Title;

      procedure Update_Title (Self : in out Message_Type; Title : String) is
      begin
         Self.Title := To_Unbounded_String (Title);
      end Update_Title;

      function "=" (Left, Right : Message_Type) return Boolean is
      begin
         return Left.Title = Right.Title;
      end "=";

   end Message;

   package Message_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Index_Type => Natural,
      Element_Type => Message.Message_Type, "=" => Message."=");

   package Message_Access_Vector is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Index_Type => Natural,
      Element_Type => Message.Message_Type_Access, "=" => Message."=");

   Messages       : Message_Vector.Vector;
   Message_Cursor : Message_Vector.Cursor;

   Messages_Access       : Message_Access_Vector.Vector;
   Message_Access_Cursor : Message_Access_Vector.Cursor;

   First_Message  : Message.Message_Type;
   Second_Message : Message.Message_Type_Access;

begin
   First_Message := Message.Create_Message ("First");

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (First_Message.Get_Title);

   First_Message.Update_Title ("First changed");

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (First_Message.Get_Title);

   First_Message.Update_Title ("First");

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (First_Message.Get_Title);

   --

   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;

   Messages.Append (First_Message);

   Message_Cursor := Message_Vector.First (Messages);

   while Message_Vector.Has_Element (Message_Cursor) loop
      declare
         Temporary_Message : Message.Message_Type;
      begin
         Temporary_Message := Message_Vector.Element (Message_Cursor);
         Temporary_Message.Update_Title ("First changed");
      end;

      Message_Vector.Next (Message_Cursor);
   end loop;

   Message_Cursor := Message_Vector.First (Messages);

   while Message_Vector.Has_Element (Message_Cursor) loop
      --
      -- Prints "First" and not "First changed"
      --
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Message_Vector.Element (Message_Cursor).Get_Title);

      Message_Vector.Next (Message_Cursor);
   end loop;

   --

   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;

   Second_Message := Message.Create_Message_Access ("Second");

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Second_Message.all.Get_Title);
   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Second_Message.Get_Title);

   --

   Ada.Text_IO.New_Line;

   Messages_Access.Append (Second_Message);

   Message_Access_Cursor := Message_Access_Vector.First (Messages_Access);

   while Message_Access_Vector.Has_Element (Message_Access_Cursor) loop
      declare
         Temporary_Message : Message.Message_Type_Access;
      begin
         Temporary_Message := Message_Access_Vector.Element (Message_Access_Cursor);
         Temporary_Message.Update_Title ("Second changed");
      end;

      Message_Access_Vector.Next (Message_Access_Cursor);
   end loop;

   Message_Access_Cursor := Message_Access_Vector.First (Messages_Access);

   while Message_Access_Vector.Has_Element (Message_Access_Cursor) loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Message_Access_Vector.Element (Message_Access_Cursor).Get_Title);

      Message_Access_Vector.Next (Message_Access_Cursor);
   end loop;

end Main;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The two primitive operations Create_Message and Create_Message_Access can be used to create concrete message objects. I'm not really sure if the primitive operation should return the type Message_Type or Message_Type_Access. Which type is recommended (efficiency?) or are both solutions are not optimal?

Which is best depends on the circumstances. In general it's best to avoid pointers, but if the thing you're representing is an object with permanence in your system you need to have only one copy of it, as you've found. I've made them limited, and used containers of pointers.

> I think in the first way the object is created on the stack and then copied after the return statement is executed because the variable Object goes out of scope. Right or wrong?

It'd be copied during the return statement, I think, but aside from that, yes (there are circumstances involving limited types where you can 'build the object in place', but the rules have changed between language standard releases, so I'm not sure; see [AARM 7.6(17.1)](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/aarm12_w_tc1/html/AA-7-6.html#p17.1) and prepare to be baffled).

> I think in the second way the object is created on the heap and then the pointer is copied after the return statement is executed because the variable Object goes out of scope. Right or wrong?

Again, yes.

> ... I assume calling the operation Message_Vector.Element (Message_Cursor) returns only a copy of the message stored in the vector. Right or wrong?

Yes.

> Last question: What is the difference between Second_Message.all.Get_Title and Second_Message.Get_Title?

In this case, none. But if the procedure was parameterless, you'd  need to use the first form, because it wouldn't be obviously a subprogram call.

---

The operations like `Element` do indeed return a copy. If you want to update the element in the container, you could take a copy, modify it, and then use `Replace_Element` to overwrite the original.

You'd probably find it less cumbersome (but only just) to use `Update_Element`:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
procedure Updating_Messages is
   type Message is record
      N : Integer := 0;
   end record;
   package Message_Vectors is
     new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Index_Type => Positive,
                                 Element_Type => Message);
   Messages : Message_Vectors.Vector;
begin
   Messages.Append (Message'(N => 21));                                     -- sorry about this, failing of Google syntax highlighting '
   Messages.Append (Message'(N => 42));                                     --'
   for Cursor in Messages.Iterate loop
      declare
         procedure Increment (It : in out Message) is
         begin
            It.N := It.N + 1;
         end Increment;
      begin
         Messages.Update_Element (Cursor, Increment'Access);                --'
      end;
   end loop;
   for M of Messages loop  -- these are copies
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (M.N'Image);                                     --'
   end loop;
end Updating_Messages;
```

Comment: If I should decide to use pointers only: Would `type Message_Type (<>) is tagged limited private;` be a useful definition for the type?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I did. Of course (!) you do end up having to manage deallocation somehow (perhaps via `Ada.Finalization`).

Comment: If I declare the type for my messages as `type Message_Type (<>) is tagged limited `: Let's imagine that I am not interesed in providing a `Create` function with the return type `Create_Message_Access`. Could a procedure in another package take the type `Message_Type` as a parameter and then create a copy of this message to a variable with an `access` type so the copied message could be stored in a vector (`Message_Access_Vector`)?

Comment: If you want to copy the message, you can either not make it `limited` or provide a `Copy` subprogram in the first package (it’d then be a different message with the same contents, presumably; that might not be sensible in your system).